# Should this roof be fixed now (shingles)?

Tags: roof, roofing, shingles

My wife and I just bought a house, and it looks like the previous owners did a partial repair job on the roof. Shingles on the front of the house look OK, but the back not so much. I see some granules in my gutters, some damaged and curling shingles. It is especially bad on the flatter parts of the roof over the windows (back of the house).

I'm just looking for opinions on proper procedure here. Do you think this is something that needs an immediate intervention, or am I OK to wait for a few years? Can I just do a partial job to fix the worst parts, or would it not be worth it?

Photo gallery: https://carousel.dropbox.com/photos/cc/lU58DzGUtxUIS7B

Comment: That doesn't look alarming to me. Have you inspected the underside for evidence of water infiltration?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I visited the attic a few weeks ago and saw some darker traces on the wood, but my sense is that this must have been from an older episode. I think there must have been infiltration, and the previous owners patched things up without changing the boards.

Comment: I don't think you'd see infiltration on the shed roof sections that are the worst, as they probably don't have attic above them. And @longneck, are you really not alarmed by the 3rd picture?

Comment: Please upload pictures here.

Comment: Please upload pictures to SE's imgur tool to avoid having the photo link go bad in the future. After doing so, please tag me in the comments here so this question can be reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Get the curling ones fixed. As you're getting quotes for that, ask for a quote for an entire re-roof and decide for yourself. (If it was me and I had the money, I'd re-roof entirely to save the bother of having segments out-of-sync, but I understand the way new home ownership goes.)